# EGL error: 0x3003, The camera device has encountered a serious error (Camera2 Api)

Tags: android, android-camera2

I am writing a app control flash camera mobile, i can control flash on or off. But it only works a few times and then it crashed.

I don't understand the reason it's crash. I'm very tired.

This is my code:

```
class FlashActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1

private var sX = 0f
private var sY = 0f
private lateinit  var button: Button
private lateinit var camManager: CameraManager
private lateinit var camDevice: CameraDevice
private lateinit var request: CaptureRequest.Builder
private lateinit var camSession: CameraCaptureSession

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flash)
    getScreen()
    setUI()
    init()
}

private fun openCamera(){
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA)
    }else{
        if(getListCamera().lastIndex > 0)
            camManager.openCamera(getListCamera()[0], OpenCallback(), null)
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "this device is not support", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

private fun init(){
    camManager = this.getSystemService(android.content.Context.CAMERA_SERVICE) as CameraManager
    openCamera()
}

private fun getListCamera(): List<String> {
    var list = listOf<String>()
    for (i in camManager.cameraIdList){
        list += i
    }
    return list
}

private fun event(){
    var i = 0
    button.setOnClickListener{
        if(i%2 == 0) {
            button.text = "On"
            request.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)
        }
        else{
            button.text = "Off"
            request.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_OFF)
        }
        camSession.setRepeatingRequest(request.build(), null, null)
        i++
    }
}

private fun setUI(){
    button = Button(this)
    button.isActivated = false
    button.text = "Off"
    button.measure(0, 0)
    rl_flash_activity.addView(button)
    button.x = sX*50 - button.measuredWidth/2
    button.y = sY*50

}

private fun getScreen(){
    val manager = windowManager.defaultDisplay
    val point  = Point()
    manager.getSize(point)
    sX = point.x/100f
    sY = point.y/100f
}

inner class OpenCallback: CameraDevice.StateCallback(){
    override fun onOpened(camera: CameraDevice) {
        Log.d("camera", "opened")
        camDevice = camera
        request = camDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE)

        val texture = SurfaceTexture(1)
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(1, 1)
        request.addTarget(Surface(texture))

        val outputSurface = ArrayList<Surface>(1)
        outputSurface.add(Surface(texture))
        try {
            camDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurface, CameraCaptureSessionCallBack(), null)
        }catch (e: Exception){}
        event()
    }

    override fun onDisconnected(camera: CameraDevice) {
    }

    override fun onError(camera: CameraDevice, error: Int) {
        Log.d("camera", "err")
    }
}

open inner class CameraCaptureSessionCallBack: CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback(){
    override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
        Log.d("CaptureSession", "false")
    }

    override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
        camSession = session
        camSession.setRepeatingRequest(request.build(), null, null)
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA) {
        // Request for camera permission.
        if (grantResults.size == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission has been granted. Start camera preview Activity.
            openCamera()
        } else {
            // Permission request was denied.
            Toast.makeText(this, "permission is not granded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
}
```

Logcat:

> 07-28 03:59:14.834 7479-7525/com.example.root.flash
>   E/CameraDeviceGLThread-0: Received exception on GL render thread: 
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: swapBuffers: EGL error: 0x3003
>           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.swapBuffers(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:535)
>           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.drawIntoSurfaces(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:751)
>           at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.GLThreadManager$1.handleMessage(GLThreadManager.java:105)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 07-28 03:59:14.969 7479-7479/com.example.root.flash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.root.flash, PID: 7479
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>        Caused by: android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): The camera device has encountered a serious error
>           at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:2023)
>           at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.submitCaptureRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:891)
>           at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraDeviceImpl.java:938)
>           at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.setRepeatingRequest(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:243)
>           at com.example.root.flash.FlashActivity$event$1.onClick(FlashActivity.kt:80)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22433)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6186)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. I moved `val texture = SurfaceTexture(1)` to `onCreate()` and it is working fine